# Using insertBefore to insert HTML table into the correct child div

Tags: html, queryselector

I have the following code that inserts a table into a div using `insertBefore`, but I'm struggling to get the positioning of the table correct:

```
//function creates standard HTML table   
const table = createTable({ data, propertyId });

let wrapper = document.querySelector(classes.propertySummary);
wrapper.insertBefore(table, wrapper.children[1]);
```

Produces the following in the DOM:

```
<div class="summary">
   <div>Where my table should sit inside</div>
   <table></table>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: I'm not seeing an issue here (based on the code provided). You are using `insertBefore()` to place your table before `wrapper.children[1]`, which is the 2nd child of the `wrapper` variable you declared. The output places your table before the 2nd child (making it the new 2nd child).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`wrapper.children[1]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/children) returns the second DIV inside `<div class="summary">`. [`insertBefore()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) inserts an element inside the element that calls `insertBefore()`, in this case `wrapper` which returns `<div class="summary">`. The second parameter provided to `insertBefore()` determines the place among, and alongside, the list of children the first parameter is placed.

The TABLE is inserted *before* the second DIV `.children[1]`, positioning the TABLE *after* the first DIV, not *inside* the first DIV.

To get there dig just a bit deeper. Here's one way:

```
let wrapper = document.querySelector(classes.propertySummary + " div");
```

Appending `+ " div"` to the [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), returns `".summary div"`. This selects the first DIV inside `<div class="summary">`.

Outputs:

```
<div class="summary">
   <div>
      Where my table should sit inside
      <table></table>
   </div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

Be sure `classes.propertySummary` returns `".summary"`—notice the preceding dot. If not, use `"." + classes.propertySummary + " div"` for the `querySelector()` parameter.

```js
const classes = {"propertySummary": ".summary"}, data = "", propertyId = "";
function createTable (obj) {
  return document.createElement("table");
}

//function creates standard HTML table   
const table = createTable({ data, propertyId });

let wrapper = document.querySelector(classes.propertySummary + " div");
wrapper.insertBefore(table, wrapper.children[1]);
```

```html
<div class="summary">
   <div>Where my table should sit inside</div>
   <div></div>
</div>
```

```
wrapper.insertBefore(table, wrapper.children[1]);
```

...is superfluous. [`appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

```
wrapper.appendChild(table);
```

...produces the same result.